# Flutter - Textformfield do not work as expected when text overflows the input

Tags: flutter

I need one line input, but user can enter many characters... When text entered to input overflows the size, the text disappears like this:

[image]

Instead of maintain the same line, and let me scroll to left or right through the comment

```
Row(children: [
    Expanded(
      flex: 8,
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
            ),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              width: 0,
              style: BorderStyle.none,
            ),
          ),
          labelText: 'Type your comment',
          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
        ),
        inputFormatters: [
          LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(102),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 3,
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.green,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0)),
        ),
        child: Text(
          'Comment',
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .caption
              .copyWith(fontSize: 9, color: Theme.of(context).buttonColor),
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    )
  ]),
```

Comment: Share the snippet of your code

Comment: Share the code.

Comment: Code snippet added

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap textField in a container and also you can set max and min line as "1" as a property inside of textField. 
This works for me :)

Comment: Not working... I shared the code I use... Maybe some error on my code

Comment: you should try by removing input formators and adding maxLines, minLines, maxLength parameters of textFormField.. Though I have gone through the code above I could not found any irrelavent with the question. InputFormators was throwing error while implemanting in dart pad online, but after removing it and adding the above suggestions, It workd fine for me.

Comment: Removing input formator and adding maxLines: 1, minLines: 1, maxLength: 255 does not work

Comment: Have you tried running the code in different os or device ?

Answer (score 0):

use TextformField instead and content padding the field

```dart
    InputDecorationTheme inputDecorationTheme() {

      OutlineInputBorder outlineInputBorder = OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xff0D3552)),
            gapPadding: 10,
      );
      return InputDecorationTheme(    
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
        enabledBorder: outlineInputBorder,
        focusedBorder: outlineInputBorder,
        border: outlineInputBorder,
      );
    }
```